# Selecting from an array of Text Inputs with Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I'm using SimpleForm in Rails 4. I am trying to do something like this:

```
<%= f.input :options_for_example, collection: ["Option1", "Option2", "Option3","Option4"], :as => :radio_buttons, :item_wrapper_class => 'inline'%>
```

This syntax (similar) works in Formtastic but SimpleForm uses Bootstrap so I am using SimpleForm. What do I need to add to make this work?

My error is `No input found for radio_buttons`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Add `gem simple_form, '3.0.0rc'` into your Gemfile an run `bundle install`

Then in the view use the following code:

```
<%= f.input :options_for_example, collection: [ ['option1', 'Option 1' ], ['option2', 'Option 2'], ['option3', 'Option 3' ], ['option4', 'Option 4' ] ], as: :radio_buttons, item_wrapper_class: 'inline'%>
```

I am using it in selecting the Gender Male or Female with the following (in case you need it):

```
<%= f.input :gender, label: 'What is your gender?', collection: [ ['M', 'Male' ], ['F', 'Female'] ], as: :radio_buttons, label_method: :last, value_method: :first, checked: @student.gender, item_wrapper_class: 'inline'%>
```

Comment: Same issue with that approach, but that is what I've seen. Passing in a 'label' and a 'value' for each.

Comment: but this should work , it works for me , and i got it from the documentation. what error do you see ?

Comment: this from the documentation https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collection-radio-buttons

Comment: Your code works. Add this to your answer:

The `gem 'simple_form'` by default, will download simple form 1.4.1. This version does not behave the same. We must download `gem simple_form, '3.0.0rc`